# Removing garbage characters from line / Robust XML parser in python

Tags: python, xml, linux, shell, unix

I have a file which contains corrupt XML, There are some garbage characters at the end of line that I want to get rid of. These garbage characters do not allow me to use Python's XML parser.  Example:

```
<request><pair><name>q</name><value><![CDATA[LOL]]></value></pair><pair><name>start</name><value>1</value></pair></request>�J I�i�Y�Y��'z�3�u�J�5��}���#Q/k;!�ˑ�9Q){_������ŐF
<request><pair><name>q</name><value><![CDATA[LOL2]]></value></pair><pair><name>start</name><value>1</value></pair></request>4/lIT�l��'�c�Oֲ�{�;��_?��(>͏Y�mP��
```

How can I remove the garbage characters after `</request>` ? Or in other words, How to remove string between `</request>` and `<request>` ?

Please note from `<request>` to `</request>` is just one line so

Code:

```
awk '/<request>/ , /<\/request>/' test.txt
```

does not work.

My purpose is to extract value when name is "q" (LOL and LOL2) in this case. So if that can be done easily, I am not bothered about removing the junk characters.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Why not filter the garbage characters before parsing the XML?.

Comment: How do I filter? I cannot change the module which prints this XML. So all I have is a file with garbage characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can extract data using lxml and xpath expressions-

```
import lxml
from lxml import etree
source_xml = " path to your xml file"
et = etree.parse(source_xml)
value = et.xpath("//document/request/pair[name='q']/value/text()")
print " ".join(value)
```

I tried this using your given xml sample and my output is `'LOL LOL2'`

Comment: I finally managed to install lxml, but I get error in line "etree.parse" ? (File contents are same as in example). Please help. Very new python convert.

Comment: ok, try doing this- add `<document>` tag in beginning of the file, than add `</document>` tag in the end of file. may be this can help

Comment: Yep, that was the issue. Thank you so much! Learned many new things today. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

This works but it probably isn't the most efficient way to do it:

```
>>> f = open('x.txt','r')
>>> z = ["%s</request>" % x.split('</request>')[0] for x in f.readlines()]
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you back the file, including line separators, without any garbage character.
(note: the "with" statement is for Python 2.6+, for previous versions just open() and then .close() the file)

```
import re
clean = ''
with open('x.txt','r') as f:
  clean = "".join([ line[:re.search('<\/request>',line).end()] for line in f ])
```

Comment: Regular expression FTW!, Thanks